# Update an existing collection mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection

```
   {
    "_id" : 100000001,
    "horses" : []
    "race" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-06-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-06-05T02:40:00.000Z"),
        "type" : "Flat",
        "name" : "Hindwoods Maiden Stakes (Div I)",
        "run_befor" : 11,
        "finish" : null,
        "channel" : "ATR",
    },
    "track" : {
        "fences" : 0,
        "omitted" : 0,
        "hdles" : 0,
        "name" : "Lingfield",
        "country" : "GB",
        "type" : "",
        "going" : "Good"
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to update it

```
@result value

{
    "race":{
      "run_after":"10",
      "finish":{
      "time":152.34,
      "slow":1,
      "fast":0,
      "gap":5.34
    }
},
    "track":{
      "name":"Lingfield",
      "country":"GB",
      "type":"",
      "going":"Good",
      "fences":0,
      "omitted":0,
      "hdles":0
    }
}

Card.where(_id:100000001).update(@result)
```

When I update the collection of all data is deleted and inserted new
If do set() same

How do to upgrade the existing collection records are updated and not existing added?

Comment: I found the solution!

`{
    "race.run_after": 10,
    "race.finish":
    "race.finish.time":152.34,
    "race.finish.slow":1,
    "race.finish.fast":0,
    "track": ....

}`

Comment: If you found the solution you should post it as an answer to your own question.